# Calculation of Killing Spinors on the 2-Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, spinors, clifford-algebra

A Killing spinor on a Riemannian spin manifold $\mathcal{M}$ is a spinor field
$\psi$  which satisfies
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_{X}\psi = \lambda X\cdot\psi
\end{equation}
for all tangent vectors $X$, where
$\nabla$ is the spinor covariant derivative,
$\cdot$  is Clifford multiplication and
${\displaystyle \lambda \in \mathbb{C}}$ is a constant, called the Killing number of
$\psi $. If
$\lambda =0$ then the spinor is called a parallel spinor.

I have been told that somehow for $\mathcal{M} = S^{2}$ the equation reduces to
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_{\mu}\psi = \pm\frac{1}{2}\gamma_{\mu}\psi
\end{equation}
where we have introduced the 2d-Clifford algebra. How does one go about deriving this expression?

Comment: Can you be more precise what's unclear to you here? That the equation has to hold for all $X$ means it has to hold for the basic vector fields $\partial_\mu$, and plugging that and the definition of "Clifford multiplication" in should result in the equation for $S^2$.

Comment: I am more curios about how the factor of $\lambda = \pm 1/2$ arises. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: ...shouldn't that just come from your definition of "Clifford multiplication"? What *is* your definition of "Clifford multiplication", and what problem do you have in applying it here?